# Creating table using div structure

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I'm trying to accomplish this sort of layout..

[image]

Notice how the text is always vertical centered. I want to achieve that using vertical-align with divs.

Note: Blocks don't have a specific height. Using properties like `top:50%` or positioning won't achieve exact centering.

http://jsfiddle.net/V8S8b/

Comment: Can you post a demo of what you've got so far at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com)?

Comment: sure! added js fiddle link to post! For some reason it's not vertical aligned either and `border-bottom` for li doesn't work

Comment: ok vertical center works now. I had the img in the .inner div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the image. The work around is to separate the image and the text content into two separate 'cells' which will correctly determine the alignment. Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/YRvhN/) - I've had to set some width's for the containers but since they are acting as table cells they will adjust according to content (as I have tried to demonstate)

Answer (score 0):

```
.ul.entries li {
    display:table-row;
    padding:8px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

You have an error here. ul should not be preceded by dot  since its not a class .Rest looks fine.

Comment: fixed. there's no dot in my original code and padding still has no effect :(

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, I edited the jsfiddle link you gave above and managed to get a similar layout to the picture you included above.

```
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.entries {
    width:500px;
}

ul.entries li {
    margin: 10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

.inner {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul.entries li img {
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: thanks but like I mentioned, I'm trying to create a table with a div structure using `vertical-align:middle` The solution you provided isn't relevant